# Install tomcat7 on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: apt, 17.10, tomcat7

Preferably through apt-get. I know there's [this](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/tomcat7) package for 16.04, but I don't know how to add it to apt-get. Would it work?

I have java8 installed. Not sure what additional information I can provide.

I also found this: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/artful/+source/tomcat7 which is for 17.10

Answer (score 0):

Everything in the Ubuntu repositories is already "in" apt-get.

`tomcat7` is in the Universe repository (exception: 14.04 it's in
    Main).

Here are the steps:

1. *Enable* [the Universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) if needed.
2. *Update* your system's database of available software packages using the command

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. *Install* the software and all required dependencies using

   ```
   sudo apt-get install tomcat7
   ```

Comment: When I type `sudo apt-get install tomcat`  and press tab, it goes straight to `tomcat8` and there is no sight of the tomcat7 packages. I figured I need to add some kind of repository to apt.

Comment: @m_highlanderish  Ah, I understand. The answer is now revised to help you enable Ubuntu's repository, where t7 lives.